# GKLocalPlayer isAuthenticated property always return NO

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

i use to check if a local player authenticated  with Game Center with Block of code

```
if ([[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] isAuthenticated]) 
{
    NSLog(@"authenticated");
}
```

this code runs when i first login with GameCenter. When i kill my app and start again it returns NO (Player is not authenticated)

Do i have to login each time when i start the app?
Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to authenticate localPlayer every time your app becomes active but the user only has to input his user/password info the first time. After that it "remembers" who the user is.

Note that the authentication method in iOS 5 is not the same as iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to call authenticatedPlayer every time your app starts. First time iOS will prompt the user for GameCenter permission. Don't worry to call login, once the user select GameCenter allowed,  it will be login automatically authenticated.